# ActiveRecord charting tool

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, charts, analytics

I'm wondering if there's any Rails tools which would automatically generate charts based on ActiveRecord dates, e.g. using `created_at` to show records created per time. I see there's RailsMetrics, but it doesn't

Comment: Why it should be a chart tool, why not some rake task for generating report?

Comment: I'm thinking of something like the Rails admin tools. But could be a rake task, if something like that is out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was looking for in the [admin_data](https://github.com/bigbinary/admin_data) tool. It's a similar tool to ActiveAdmin, RailsAdmin, etc, but I discovered that when you're browsing a record, you also get an Analytics option. Example:

[image: example chart from test server]